# Debugging Deployed AppEngine Flex nodejs App

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to get the [Plaid nodejs quickstart](https://github.com/plaid/quickstart) running through an AppEngine Flex app.

Following the [App Engine Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-node/index.html#0), I've made it to the point where I can run `npm start` and get the app working on the 8080 port. I then ran `gcloud app deploy`, which ran without any errors.

However, when I navigate to the given `{my-app-name}.uc.r.appspot.com` site, it hangs indefinitely and there are no errors when I look at the Cloud Shell command line.

Looking at `gcloud app describe` gives:

```
{my_username}@cloudshell:~/quickstart/node$ gcloud app describe                                                                                                                                                            
authDomain: gmail.com
codeBucket: staging.{my-app-name}.appspot.com
databaseType: CLOUD_FIRESTORE
defaultBucket: {my-app-name}.appspot.com
defaultHostname: {my-app-name}.uc.r.appspot.com
featureSettings:
  splitHealthChecks: true
  useContainerOptimizedOs: true
gcrDomain: us.gcr.io
id: {my-app-name}
locationId: us-central
name: apps/{my-app-name}
servingStatus: SERVING
```

I also looked at the [Error Reporting piece](https://console.cloud.google.com/errors) of the Google Cloud Console and there are no errors reported.

Any ideas how to debug or figure out what may be going on? It's confusing to me that it ran "locally". I'd appreciate guidance towards how to debug or things to look at as right now, I have very little to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found the issue:
[The logs are available here](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer).

And for completeness sake, my issue was that I didn't have all IPs available in the `app.listen()` method in my script.